# Pagination and manipulating lists in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need help with creating and paginating a list in Rails. I have three classes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rankings, :dependent => :destroy
  #...
  # has id, name, email, etc. 
end

class Ranking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :essay
  belongs_to :user
  #...
  #has comment, score, essay_id, user_id
end

class Essay < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rankings, :dependent => :destroy
  #...
  #has id, body, author, etc.
end
```

The Ranking class gets created as a review of each essay and then then get its `essay_id` and `user_id` set accordingly so we know who ranked which essay.

Now on the home page of the application I want to display a paginated list of all essays which the user has not ranked yet. I want as list of **all the essays that the `current_user` has not raked**. For all essays I simple do `@essays = Essay.paginate(:page => params[:page])` but I want a particular subset of these. Do I need to create an array of the unranked essays?

Answer (score 0):

This is one suggestion, not using joins.

First get all the ids of essays the user has ranked

```
essay_ids = User.first.essay_ids
```

Then get all essays not containing these ids ;)

```
@essays = Essay.where('id NOT IN (?)', essay_ids + [0])
```

I like to add the extra 0, so that an empty array won't screw up the query.

You could plant this in a scope in Essay

```
scope :not_ranked_by_user, lambda {|user| where('id NOT IN (?)', user.essay_ids + [0]) }
```

Comment: does rails make the .essay_ids method if I have a .essay_id attribute? and the users dont have an essay_id so I can't get the list of essay_ids that way. does that return an array? Im sure i could figure out how to get everything in an array, but pagination doesnt really work on arrays. how do I paginate the :not_ranked_by_user too? sorry... lots of questions